# RegEx works on Brower as well as Node Terminal but not in a Node Program?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, browser, terminal

I have a code snippet that uses regex. It works very well in browser terminal as well as Node Terminal. But the moment I write this into a file and use node to execute it throws an error stating that the output is `null`. I have no Idea why is that happening. The snippet is as follows:-

```js
function getFileName(path) {
    return path.match(/^((http[s]?|ftp):\/)?\/?([^:\/\s]+)(:([^\/]*))?((\/[\w\/-]+)*\/)([\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?$/i);
}

var k = getFileName('http://google.com');
console.log(k)
```

In the case of the snippet on Stackoverflow too this is giving a null. But try to run this on browser or node terminal and you would see a result of Array.

What am I doing wrong?

NOTE: This RegEx is for getting different part of the URL.

Comment: Doesn't work in the snippet, doesn't work in Chrome's console. Where is the working code?

Comment: Also just tried it in Nodejs with the same result. The regex doesn't match the input.

Comment: It matches `http://google.com/hello`. It seems there needs to be something in the path after the domain. I don't feel like trawling any further through that nasty regex to find out why, though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this part `((/[\w/-]+)*/)`
It is required and it *has* to have 2 forward slashes.

You seem to compensate by putting the optional `/?` after http:/ but
it's not enough because to match optional http:/, it takes one of the slashes.

There is another part of your regex that is fixed as well but I don't know
what that's intended for.

To fix the regex so it matches the domain part, make `((/[\w/-]+)*/)` optional.

And, it would help if the first part is `^((http[s]?|ftp)://|/)?`

Raw:

```
^((http[s]?|ftp)://|/)?([^:/\s]+)(:([^/]*))?((/[\w/-]+)*/)?([\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)(\?([^#]*))?(\#(.*))?$
```

Toothpicked:

```
/^((http[s]?|ftp):\/\/|\/)?([^:\/\s]+)(:([^\/]*))?((\/[\w\/-]+)*\/)?([\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)(\?([^#]*))?(\#(.*))?$/
```

Expanded (raw):

```
 ^ 
 (                             # (1 start)
      ( http [s]? | ftp )           # (2)
      ://
   |  /
 )?                            # (1 end)

 ( [^:/\s]+ )                  # (3)
 (                             # (4 start)
      :
      ( [^/]* )                     # (5)
 )?                            # (4 end)
 (                             # (6 start)
      ( / [\w/-]+ )*                # (7)
      /
 )?                            # (6 end)
 ( [\w\-\.]+ [^#?\s]+ )        # (8)
 (                             # (9 start)
      \?
      ( [^#]* )                     # (10)
 )?                            # (9 end)
 (                             # (11 start)
      \#
      ( .* )                        # (12)
 )?                            # (11 end)
 $
```